# SharePoint calulated field count if

Tags: sharepoint, calculated-columns

I have a sharepoint list with 3 columns query, response(yes/no), calculated field.

there are 100 questions under query column & yes/no response need to be captured at response column

in calculated filed I need to show the total result. each yes carry 1 number hence if there are 68 yes & 32 no for a candidate than calculated field should show 68 as total marks.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: Is this a list with 3 columns and 100 items/rows?  And the is total for the entire list, or per set of 100 columns?

Comment: @MikeSmith-MCT-MVP I was unable to dealt with calculated field so I delivered the solution with info-path for library. yes it was 100 questions so 100 columns(choise yes/no). I used info-path formula to apply the logic.